# What method is called when a user taps on a tab bar. I need to refresh tabs content

Tags: ios

I would like my app to automatically refresh contents of a tab when a user taps on the corresponding tab bar.
Once the app is loaded and in the memory, it always loads the existing content of the tab. I have a image on the tab that I want to update/refresh when user tabs on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the void `viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear & viewDidAppear` methods of the view controller linked to the tab.

You'll probably want to go with `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` as these are called every time these views will/did appear as opposed to the first time they load before they initially appear.

Comment: are these events of each view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Look at **UITabBarDelegate**. It has a method **tabBar:didSelectItem:** that is called whenever the user selects a particular tab bar item.